# Rendering of Devanagari font while using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, showtext

here is the reproducible example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(showtext)

## Sahitya font for Devanagari characters

font_add_google("Sahitya")
showtext_auto()


p = ggplot(NULL, aes(x = 1, y = 1)) + ylim(0.8, 1.2) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank()) +
  annotate("text", 1, 0.9, family = "Sahitya", size = 15,
           label = "मित्र ") 

print(p)
```

Actual rendering should be **मित्र** (meaning is friend)

Answer (score 0):

Twitter helped to get the answer. #Rstats community is the best.
here are the details

[Twitter Help by RStats Community](https://twitter.com/CedScherer/status/1344294597711822850?s=20)

Additionally please refer [ragg Package](https://ragg.r-lib.org)

Solution

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ragg)

file <- knitr::fig_path('.png')
agg_png(file)

ggplot(NULL, aes(x = 1, y = 1)) + ylim(0.8, 1.2) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank()) +
  annotate("text", 1, 0.9, family = "Sahitya", size = 15,
           label = "मित्र ") 

invisible(dev.off())
```

However I observed you have to download and add the font first.
Hence removed :

```
## Sahitya font for Devanagari characters

font_add_google("Sahitya")
showtext_auto()
```